# Django REST Framework API Management

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make certain attributes related to my APIs configurable (these are unrelated to DRF attributes), it's more of meta data that I would like to utilize for my own application. For this purpose, I'm creating an app I'm calling `apimanager` for the sole purpose of API management.

The way I'm imagining this to be implemented is by discovering all the APIs defined within DRF and then define a `ModelAdmin` class to manage the APIs along with their attributes.

**API Discovery**

Approach 1: Import the list of defined urls in `urls.py` and filter it with a prefix (e.g. ^api) - I don't like this since it relies on convention and it also led to circular imports.

Approach 2: Define my APIs in `module/api/view/` folder and find the classes defined in each python file - I don't like this as well.

Approach 3: Go through each module and find classes that are sublcasses of `APIView` and then define a model to for the relevant meta data, something like this:

```
class API(models.Model):
    from modules.companies.api.view import companies
    _apis = (
        (x,x) for x in (lambda m: [
            m.__dict__[c] for c in m.__dict__ if (
                isinstance(m.__dict__[c], type) and m.__dict__[c].__module__ == m.__name__
            )
        ])(companies) if issubclass(x, APIView)
    )

    api = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=_apis)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'API'
        verbose_name_plural = 'APIs'
```

*Ignore the in-class import and `companies` instance, these are used for testing purposes.*

This approach works if I go through each module I have in my application, but it feels like a bit hacky and I feel like there is a simpler, more elegant way of doing this.

How would you approach this problem? How would you design your API management app?

Comment: Have you thought about writing a small registration mechanism and then from within your code calling something like `apimanager.register(MyApiView)`? After your app started you could iterate over all registered classes and implement your business logic. That's not a *very clever* mechanism, but it reads well and feels close to Django's own mechanism to register things (admin, filters, templatetags, ...).

Comment: @sthzg I like this idea, I'm gonna try to implement something and post it as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @sthzg's comment, I made a registration-based approach which works out pretty well.

**registration.py:**

```
def register_api(cls):
    try:
        # check for membership
        api = API.objects.get(
            module=cls.__class__.__module__,
            name=cls.__class__.__name__,
        )

        # update api
    except API.DoesNotExist:
        # register api
        api = API(
            module=cls.__class__.__module__,
            name=cls.__class__.__name__,
        )
        api.save()
```

**models.py:**

```
class API(models.Model):
    module = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def get_class(self):
        return locate('%s.%s' % (self.module, self.name))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'API'
        verbose_name_plural = 'APIs'
        unique_together = ('module', 'name')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name
```

And for any API that I want to register:

```
class APIManagerMember(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(APIManagerMember, self).__init__()
        register_api(self)


class CompanyViewSet(APIManagerMember, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'company_id'
```

Inheriting all DRF APIs from `APIManagerMember` will automatically build a list of all your APIs. This is a starting point for a building an API catalog and it can be extended for building a bigger api management package.